Density Matrices for states $|+\rangle$ and state represented by $\rho = \frac{|0\rangle \langle0| + |1\rangle \langle1|}{2}$
As per my understanding, the first one is a "pure state" and represents a system with one qubit having equal probability of being measured as $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ (standard basis measurements).
But isn't the Second one (a mixed state) offering the same information in the context of the probability of outcomes (50% for both, same as $|+\rangle$)?
However, both of these do not have the same density matrices but are "indistinguishable" when it comes to standard basis measurements. Could someone help clear my confusion/clarify my understanding of this?

You are right that these two are in essence indistinguishable in the standard basis, but the key is that state $|+\rangle$ is deterministic in the Hadamard basis.
If you first apply an $H$ gate and then perform measurements, the outcomes of the mixed state $\rho$ will still be either 0 or 1 with 50% probability. On the other hand, for the pure state $|+\rangle$ you will measure 0 with 100% probability.
What’s important to remember is that for any pure state, there is always a measurement basis in which the state is fully deterministic.

thank you so much for the answer, i was stuck on this for quite a while :)
